# Disable Call Waiting

Tags: calls, call-waiting

Is there a way on Android to disable call waiting?

Quite often I'll be in a conference call and suddenly one of my friends tries to call me when I'm in the middle of discussing something quite complicated.

The phone will start blipping at me to indicate the second call is coming in.
I'm really not great at multi-tasking and this completely throws me from the discussion I'm already in.

Is there a way to set the phone to redirect the secondary caller straight to voicemail?

I'm using a Motorola One Vision.

Comment: This is usually a configuration of the cell phone network. Check your mobile network provider for the necessary number codes for configuring what should happen to incoming calls if your line is busy.

Comment: I've discovered there is a setting for it in Android as my network provider didn't provide any instructions for this.  I've added it as an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

So I've discovered there is a way of doing this.
I found this answer on Quora:

https://www.quora.com/Where-is-the-call-waiting-option-on-Android-7

There's a video there and the answer is essentially :

- Open the phone app Press the Menu button (3 dots top right)
- Press   Settings
- Press Calling Accounts
- Press on your call Operator (Was EE in my case)
- Press Additional Settings
- Slide Call   Waiting to disabled

Comment: Have you tested if this results in the redirection to voicemail what you had asked for or do the caller no get the busy signal?